# OCR & OpenCV: Difference between two frames on high resolution images

Tags: c++, opencv, ocr, run-length-encoding

According to this post [OCR: Difference between two frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34024865/ocr-difference-between-two-frames), I now know how to find pixel differences between two images with OpenCV.

I would like to improve this solution and use it with high resolution images (from a video) with rich content. The example above is not applicable with big images because the process is to slow (too much differences found, the "findCountours method" fills the tab with 250k elements which takes a huge time to process).

My application uses a RLE decoder to decode the compressed frames of the video. Once the frame is decoded, I would like to compare the current frame with the previous one in order to store the differences between the two frames in a "Mat" tab for example.

The goal of all of this is to be able to perform an analysis on the different pixels and to check if there is any latin character. This allows me to reduce the amount of pixels to analyze and to save precious time.

If anyone has other ideas instead of this one to perform such operations, feel free to propose it please.

Thank you for your help.

***EDIT 1:***
Example of two high resolution images of a computer screen. These are for the moment the perfect example of what I'm trying to analyse. As we can see there is just a window as difference between the two big images and I would like to analyze just the new "Challenge" window for any character.

[image: First image]

[image: Second image]

***EDIT 2:***
I'm trying to tune the algorithm depending on the data analyzed. Typically on the two following pictures I only get the green lines as differences and no text at all (which is what is the most interesting). I'm trying to understand better how things work for this.

**1st image**:

[image: TestImg1]

**2nd image**:

[image: TestImg2]

**3rd image**: 
[image: ResultImg]

As you can see I only have those green lines and never the text (at the best I can have just ONE letter when decreasing the countours[i].size())

Comment: I'm not sure  if this helps you solving your problem, from my  experience  openCV can't handle  video in full resolution ( at least in windows http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17993677/opencv-capture-image-from-webcam-without-post-processing/17995736#17995736)

Comment: Can you post two images? Or public links to high resolution images?

Comment: @Miki I just edited my post

Comment: @Engine I'm not sure what you mean by "Can't handle video in full resolution". I'm pretty new with OpenCV so I might miss somethings. I am capable of performing operations on the entire frame of the video but this is just too long for me as it is finding too much differences between one frame and the other. The goal here is to find a way to only perform operations on the new window that appeared on the screen and not the entire frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the post you mentioned, you need to:

- When you binarize the mask, use a threshold higher then 0 to remove small differences.
- Remove some noise. You can find all connected components, and remove smaller ones.
- Find the area of the bigger connected components. You can use `convexHull` and `fillConvexPoly` to get the mask of the different objects on screen
- Copy the second image to a new image, with the given mask.

The result will look like:

[image]

Code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat3b img1 = imread("path_to_image_1");
    Mat3b img2 = imread("path_to_image_2");

    Mat3b diff;
    absdiff(img1, img2, diff);

    // Split each channel
    vector<Mat1b> masks;
    split(diff, masks);

    // Create a black mask
    Mat1b mask(diff.rows, diff.cols, uchar(0));

    // OR with each channel of the N channels mask
    for (int i = 0; i < masks.size(); ++i)
    {
        mask |= masks[i];
    }

    // Binarize mask
    mask = mask > 100;

    // Results images
    vector<Mat3b> difference_images;

    // Remove small blobs
    //Mat kernel = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(5,5));
    //morphologyEx(mask, mask, MORPH_OPEN, kernel);

    // Find connected components
    vector<vector<Point>> contours;
    findContours(mask.clone(), contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (contours[i].size() > 1000)
        {
            Mat1b mm(mask.rows, mask.cols, uchar(0));

            vector<Point> hull;
            convexHull(contours[i], hull);


            fillConvexPoly(mm, hull, Scalar(255));

            Mat3b difference_img(img2.rows, img2.cols, Vec3b(0,0,0));
            img2.copyTo(difference_img, mm);

            difference_images.push_back(difference_img.clone());
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This works very well, it is pretty fast and does exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for your help Miki !

Comment: I still have one question though. Wy did you filter the contour[i].size() to only keep those who have 1000 or more elements ? Is this a way to eliminate every "small" difference between the frames and only keep the big matches ? Is 1000 an average number ?

Comment: @DylanAlvaro Is for removing small blobs, i.e. blobs that have a (sort of) perimeter less then 1000. You can use any other value big enough, or compute it from some statistics in your image. This ` mask = mask > 100;` will eliminate small differences (< 100) between the two images.

Comment: Your additional images are very different from the initial ones, and deserve another question.